# SQL Intersection error ERROR 1064 (42000):

Tags: mysql, intersect

```sql
   create table PlatonicForms (name varchar(20), sides integer(3));
   create table Colors (hex varchar(6), color varchar(20));
   create table MorePlatonics (name varchar(20), sides integer(3));
   create table ShapesColors(color varchar(20), shape varchar(20));
```

I am trying to use this intersect

```sql
SELECT *
FROM PlatonicForms
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM MorePlatonics;
```

but I get this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM MorePlatonics' at line 3

I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I have removed the [tag:sql-server] tag, as this is clearly MySQL due to the DDL using `integer(3)` and the error. This, however, demonstrates why knowing your RDBMS is important as, according to a quick Google, MySQL does not support `INTERSECT`.

Answer (score 0):

mysql doesn't support INTERSECT syntax, try this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
   name,sides 
FROM PlatonicForms
   INNER JOIN MorePlatonics USING(name,sides);
```